# Using websockets in classic asp.net forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, asp.net-4.5

I need to add websocket functionality to legacy asp.net webforms application (just one simple long time workflow converted from old applet functionality).

I naively tried to just add websocket handler to aspx page:

```cs
        public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(HandleWebSocket);
            } else
            {
                base.ProcessRequest(context);
            }
        }
```

and enable websocket on the IIS:
[image]
Then try: `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/APP/Page.aspx");`
but this does not seam to work.

Not sure **if this is at all possible?**

Do I miss something about configuration or implementation?
I could put websocket on separate application/server but would prefer to keep it in one place with access to same session object.

Comment: Do you use IIS 8.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to handle a web socket connect in a classic ASP.NET Forms application. The tools are available on `HttpContext` and you basically have the correct idea.

I think the issue is that you are trying to invoke it from an **aspx** page and not just using a generic `IHttpHandler`. IIS runs specific processing pipelines based upon the file extension. **Aspx** is rather specialized to trying to render an HTML page, so while it might be possible to reconfigure IIS to allow websockets to interact with ASPX pages, it is much easier to just use a generic **ashx** handler.

You can create a handler by going to the "Add Item" dialog in Visual Studio
[image: Visual Studio's 'Add Item' dialog with the entry for 'Generic Handler' highlighted]

At this point, you would just implement your websocket logic in your handler code. I'm putting in a simple echo from [this aspnet sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6cc9f6f130af4ed0e7f321b144265cfbcec0ceee/src/Middleware/WebSockets/samples/AutobahnTestAppAspNet4/EchoSocket.ashx.cs) just to demonstrate.

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(EchoWebSocket);
        }
    }

    private async Task EchoWebSocket(AspNetWebSocketContext socketContext)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        var result = await socketContext.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            await socketContext.WebSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
            result = await socketContext.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        }

        await socketContext.WebSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You should now be able to connect to the websocket. Note the usage of `wss` rather than `ws`. The setup I tested with requires the secure version (wss). Use whatever is relevant for the application you are working on.

```
// Replace with port/path to your handler.
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:44336/MyHandler.ashx");

ws.onmessage = function(evt) { 
    console.log(evt); 
};

ws.send("Hello, World!");
```

And you should see output similar to this:
[image: Chrome developer console with output from the sample javascript above.]

**Note:** I generally wouldn't recommend trying to access Session data from the websocket handler. Your session may expire outside the timeframe of the websocket's lifespan. You would probably want to use some other mechanism to persist state between the socket and the rest of the pages (potentially a database or the application-level cache, which you can access from `socketContext.Cache` in the example above.

**Edit: Added an example of using session value on socket initialization.**
Per your comment, if you want to use session values during the **initialization** of a websocket (which should be a safe operation), then your handler just needs to implement `IRequiresSessionState` and needs to add a little extra syntax to pass the session value into the accept handler.

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            var sessionValue = context.Session["session_key"] as string;

            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(async (socketContext) =>
            {
                await SetupWebSocket(socketContext, sessionValue);
            });
        }
    }

    private async Task SetupWebSocket(AspNetWebSocketContext socketContext, string sessionValue)
    {
        // Handle socket as before, but 'sessionValue' is now available for use.
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seams that aspx was the problem here.

Comment: I need session for initialisation of websocket only, session itself is not aviable for handler function because it is not thread-safe.

Comment: @tester.one OK. That use case makes sense. I added another example that demonstrates how that could be done.