# How to work with WebSocket[TCP connection] in asp.net web form using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, webforms

I hope this is not a bad question rising but I want to learn this concept with good example then only I can start my Realtime work.

I'm new to this `WebSocket[TCP connection]` concept and I have read some ( [this](https://www.esegece.com/websockets/main-components/net-components) and [this](https://zetcode.com/csharp/websocket/)) content regarding this concept and I got bit basic knowledge on this but my query is, I'm unable to find the sample example tutorial on this concept(in asp.net web form using c#) that is how to create websocket(server side) and how to receive that data(from client side) basic communication between server side and client side.

Please suggest me how to work with websocket and give me basic example.

I'm very beginner in programming language.

Comment: may be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259702/using-websockets-in-classic-asp-net-forms-application) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use SignalR

SignalR is framework to communicate in real-time without polling (keep asking if there is any data to send) between server and client (browsers). Web socket is the main protocol to use in SignalR when web socket is available. If web socket is not available then SignalR will use different way to push data specially from server to the client.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/signalr-chat-app-with-asp-net-webform-and-bootstrap/